# Updating existing Health Cloud Records on form submission in Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, cloudpage, health-cloud

In Marketing Cloud, I have a CloudPages form that syncs data into my connected Health Cloud Org on form submission. I have a certain logic that determines if that user already exists in Health Cloud. If they already exist, then I only update 1 field (`@pcplist`). If they don't exist, a new Lead is created. Here is that code for updating that certain field:

```
/* Contact Check */

    set @rsContact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Id', 'FIRST_NAME_UPPER__c', '=', @fname, 'LAST_NAME_UPPER__c', '=', @lname, 'EMAIL_UPPER__c', '=', @email)

    if RowCount(@rsContact) > 0 then

      set @row = row(@rsContact, RowCount(@rsContact))

      set @contactId = Field(@row, 'Id')

      set @isContact = 'true'

    endif

    /* Lead Check */

    set @rsLead = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id', 'FIRST_NAME_UPPER__c', '=', @fname, 'LAST_NAME_UPPER__c', '=', @lname, 'EMAIL_UPPER__c', '=', @email)

    if RowCount(@rsLead) > 0 then

      set @row = row(@rsLead, RowCount(@rsLead))

      set @leadId = Field(@row, 'Id')

      set @isLead = 'true'

    endif 

    /* SF functions */

      if @isContact == 'true' then

        if @pcplist == 'true' then

        /* set @row = row(@rsContact, 1) */

        /* set @contactId = Field(@row, 'Id') */

        set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact', @contactId, 'Primary_Care_Physician__c', 'true', 'Web_Form_Submission_Date__c', @today)

        endif

      elseif @isLead == 'true' then

        if @pcplist == 'true' then

        /* set @row = row(@rsLead, 1) */

        /* set @leadId = Field(@row, 'Id') */

        set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead', @leadId, 'Primary_Care_Physician__c', 'true', 'Web_Form_Submission_Date__c', @today, 'LeadSource', 'Web Form')
        endif

      else

        set @id = CreateSalesforceObject('lead', 11, 'FirstName', @leadfirstname, 'LastName', @leadlastname, 'Email', @email,'PostalCode', @zip, 'Primary_Care_Physician__c',@pcplist,

                                   'Web_Form_Submission_Date__c', @today, 'Status', 'New', 'Web_Form_Age__c', @age, 'LeadSource', 'Web Form', 'Phone', @phone, 'Health_Wellness_Tips__c', @opt)                                 

        /*set @rsLead2 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, Email', 'FIRST_NAME_UPPER__c', '=', @fname, 'LAST_NAME_UPPER__c', '=', @lname, 'EMAIL_UPPER__c', '=', @email)

          if RowCount(@rsLead2) == 1 then

            set @isLead = 'true'

            set @row = row(@rsLead2, 1)

            set @leadId = Field(@row, 'Id')

            set @email = Field(@row, 'Email')

          endif*/           

          set @leadId = @Id

      endif
```

I tried updating the code to also update the @opt field but when I use this code, it updates BOTH the @opt and @pcplist for the existing Contact or Lead but then a duplicate Lead is created.

```
/* SF functions */
      if @isContact == 'true' then
        /* set @row = row(@rsContact, 1) */
        /* set @contactId = Field(@row, 'Id') */
        set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact', @contactId, 'Primary_Care_Physician__c', @pcplist, 'Web_Form_Submission_Date__c', @today, 'Health_Wellness_Tips__c', @opt)
        endif
      elseif @isLead == 'true' then
        /* set @row = row(@rsLead, 1) */
        /* set @leadId = Field(@row, 'Id') */
        set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead', @leadId, 'Primary_Care_Physician__c', @pcplist, 'Web_Form_Submission_Date__c', @today, 'LeadSource', 'Web Form', 'Health_Wellness_Tips__c', @opt)
        endif
      else
```

I don't want that duplicated Lead to be created. I want the logic to be:

- If this record is already a Contact --> then update the `@pcplist` (Primary_Care_Physician__c) and `@opt` (Health_Wellness_Tips__c) fields based on the values in the form submission
- If the record is already a Lead, do the same. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: So the issue is that when your `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` function is executed, you do not get the `Health_Wellness_Tips__c` field updated with the `@opt` value but it works with `Primary_Care_Physician__c` + `@pcplist`, is that correct? And then the second issue is that you have a duplicated Lead created. Please, upload your full code with Lead creation logic as well, since now it seems incomplete and hard to understand.

Comment: @Niko I updated my original post with the full code. I had inherited this code from someone else when the "@opt" field did not exist on the form". Based on the existing code, if the form submission is either a Contact or a Lead, AND "@pcplist = true", then it updates the record to mark "@pcplist" as true in Salesforce. What I want to do is UPDATE both "@pcplist" AND "@opt" as true or false in Salesforce if it's an existing Contact or Lead. However, when I use the code in the 2nd box, the logic works for the field updates BUT a duplicate Lead is created. Just updates, no extra lead in the goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you have a fully correct and working code, where you only needed to add the additional field `Health_Wellness_Tips__c` and value from `@opt` variable to both `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` functions.

However, the problem hides in your second code snippet that has a different "IF" statement, where you have extra "ENDIF" (right after each of `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` functions) - this leads to the interpretation of the code that each "IF" or "ELSEIF" is a separate statement and thus resolved separately as well, that how you can have all 3 paths to be executed at the same time if `@isContact == 'true'` and `@isLead == 'true'`.

What you need to do is simply remove extra "ENDIFs" and leave only one on the very end after the "ELSE" path.

You can review this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm), where it says that you are required to have within one "IF" statement only one "ENDIF" and then optional "ELSEIF" and "ELSE" statements.

Comment: You're awesome! That worked!